# Display value of d3.interpolate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, transition

I am quite new to `d3.js`. I am trying to understand the following code:

```
   .tween("text", function(d) {
       var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, d),
           prec = (d + "").split("."),
           round = (prec.length > 1) ? Math.pow(10, prec[1].length) : 1;

       console.log(i);

       return function(t) {
           this.textContent = Math.round(i(t) * round) / round;
       };
   });​
```

I want to see the value of `var i`, so if I am doing `console.log(i)`, I am getting some equation returned. How can I see the interpolated value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [d3.interpolate](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolate) method receives the beginning and end values of the transition, and returns an interpolator function. An interpolator function receives a value between 0 and 1, and returns the interpolated value. For instance:

```
// Create an interpolator function to compute intermediate colors between blue and red
var i = d3.interpolate('blue', 'red');

// Evaluate the interpolator
console.log(i(0.0));  // #0000ff - blue
console.log(i(0.4));  // #cc0033 - purple
console.log(i(1.0));  // #ff0000 - red
```